# QT WebView/WebKit issue

Tags: qt, webview, webkit, qml

I'm trying to add a WebView to my GUI. First, the app crashed unexpectedly everytime. I figured I probably needed to import WebKit 3.0 along with WebView 1.1. After adding the required import statement, I try to run but it says that `module "QtWebKit" is not installed`. I checked the `include` folder and its indeed not there.
[image]
So my question is if QtWebKit is what I need, how do I install it?

**Update:**
When this code exists in my `.qml` file, the app crashes without starting:

```
WebEngineView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            url: "http://www.google.com"
        }
```

This is the import statement I'm using on QT 5.6:

```
import QtWebEngine 1.1
```

This is the segmentation fault error generated because of the presence of the code mentioned above:

[image]

Full demo code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5 as QC
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.6
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0
import QtWebEngine 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    height: 640
    width: 480
    visible: true
    Loader{
        anchors.fill: parent
        sourceComponent: webComponent
    }
    Component{
        id: webComponent
        WebEngineView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: web
            profile: WebEngineProfile {
                storageName: "Default"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 different `WebView`s in Qt: One from the "Qt WebKit" module (which is now deprecated), and one from the "Qt WebView" module. They are NOT related at all! I think it was a bad mistake to use the same name for two different classes. Anyway, post more details about your crash.

Comment: @JKSH Can you please refer to my comments on the only answer?

Comment: Can you please provide details about your crashes? (How do you trigger the crashes? What error messages do you see? What do you see when you run your program with a Debugger?) Without that information, I cannot provide any useful comments.

Comment: @JKSH Apology for the delay and a great thanks for sticking with me for this long. I updated the question with the details you seek.

Comment: It looks like your crash is occurring in Qt's OpenGL functions. Questions: (1) What graphics card do you have? (2) What is your OS? (3) What happens if you run one of the official Qt WebView/Qt WebEngine examples?

Comment: @JKSH (1) `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)`
(2) Xubuntu 16.04
(3) I tried the quicknanobrowser project and it works without a problem so far.
How did you figure out it was because of QT's OpenGL functions?

Comment: @JKSH I added a demo code, this isn't working. I guess its incomplete?

Comment: Your debugger shows the function where the crash occurred. Have a closer look (it starts with "QOpenGLCont...") Did you call `QtWebEngine::initialize()`? See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine.html#initialize

Comment: @JKSH I'm sorry I didn't notice you commented. Yes that did solve the problem. If you post this as an answer I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your debugger's stack trace shows that your crash is occurring in Qt's OpenGL functions. Remember to call [`QtWebEngine::initialize()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine.html#initialize) before you start using Qt WebEngine.

Note also:

- Qt WebView is a lightweight module for running your mobile OS's native web engine. Its main QML type is called `WebView`.
- Qt WebKit is a heavyweight module for running a fully self-contained web engine. Its main QML type is also called `WebView`, but this is completely unrelated to the other `WebView`. This module is now deprecated.
- Qt WebEngine is a heavyweight module for running a fully self-contained web engine. Its main QML type is called `WebEngineView`. This module is meant to replace Qt WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Qt WebKit is a [deprecated module](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Deprecated_Modules). Maybe you can install it from Qt sources, but since you want to use WebView 1.1 (and that you're on Qt5.6), I think you'd better use [Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengine.html) (using deprecated modules is not recommended).
You can already see it in your folder (modules QtWebEngine and QtWebView).

Comment: So I shouldn't be using QtWebView either?

Comment: I added QtWebEngineView instead of QtWebView and imported QtWebEngine 1.1. The only problem now is that the app throws segmentation fault whenever the WebEngineView is present in my qml file.

Comment: The Qt WebView module is not deprecated, so it can be used today. However, it is designed for mobile platforms and its functionality is quite limited. If you want advice on whether to use Qt WebView or Qt WebEngine, please provide details on what your app does and what platforms you want to support.